# Scan and recreate QR code on Android

Tags: android, qr-code

Does anyone know of a way (preferably a single app) that could scan and recreate a QR code on Android?

Eg. I point my phone at the code, and then I could display that code on the screen, so it can be scanned again by some other device. This is different from simply taking a picture of the QR code since it takes me longer to get a nice photo of the code and even if I do, the quality is still quite bad and it takes too long to scan the code with the other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zxing library, https://github.com/zxing/zxing

**1. Store string data after scan as a bitmap:**

```js
public static Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(final String contentAfterScan, final BarcodeFormat format,
                                        final int width, final int height) throws WriterException {
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hint = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hint.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(contentAfterScan, format, width, height, hint);
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? 0xFF000000/*BLACK*/ : 0xFFFFFFFF/*WHITE*/;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

**2. Store image into your folder**

```js
private void storeImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String yourFolder, String imageName) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        File f = new File(yourFolder + File.separator + imageName);
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```